Powershell: Replacing string elements in the hashtable
I have the following Hashtable ($wImages):
Name                           Value
----                           -----
abc.png         1
def.png         1
ghk.png         1
xyz.png         1

I want to make changes in this table:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
abc.jpg         1
def.jpg         1
ghk.jpg         1
xyz.jpg         1

I use the following code to do this:
$wImages | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'png','jpg'}

But the Hashtable has no changes....
What is wrong?

A Hashtable is not a CollectionA hashtable is a collection, but PowerShell deliberately prevents the implicit enumeration of dictionaries(thanks @Mathias R. Jessen), thus is not iterable by Foearch-Object
have a easy to make generic solution:
$Hash = @{
    "abc.png" = 1
    "def.png" = 1
    "ghk.png" = 1
    "xyz.png" = 1
}

$NewHash = @{}

foreach ($Key in $Hash.keys) {
    # replace as needed
    $NewKey = $key -replace '\.png$', '.jpg'
    $NewHash.$NewKey = $Hash.$Key
}

$NewHash

resulting into:
PS > .\test.ps1
    Name                           Value
    ----                           -----
    abc.jpg                        1
    ghk.jpg                        1
    def.jpg                        1
    xyz.jpg                        1


A hashtable is a collection, but PowerShell deliberately prevents the implicit enumeration of dictionaries :)

@MathiasR.Jessen updated the explanation, thanks :)

Can't update an entry key once once added to a hashtable, you'd need to create a new hashtable.
See Remarks:

Key objects must be immutable as long as they are used as keys in the Hashtable.

$newHash = @{}
$wImages.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $newHash.Add([System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Key, 'jpg'), $_.Value)
}
$newHash


If it's important to mutate the existing hashtable rather than create a new one you can do something like this:
# set up some test data
$wImages = @{
    "something_else" = 1
    "abc.png"        = 1
    "def.png"        = 1
    "ghk.png"        = 1
    "xyz.png"        = 1
    "another_thing"  = 1
}

then remove keys of interest, and replace them with new ones:
# we have to take a *copy* of the keys because we can't iterate over them
# while also adding or removing items to the underlying collection
$keys = @( $wImages.Keys )

# remove matching keys and recreate with the new key
foreach( $key in $keys )
{
    if( $key.EndsWith(".png") )
    {
        # we can't *modify* an existing key, 
        # but we can remove it and add a new one
        $newKey = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($key, 'jpg')
        $wImages.Add($newKey, $wImages[$key]) 
        $wImages.Remove($key)
    }
}

which ends up with this:
$wImages | format-table | out-string
# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# abc.jpg                        1
# another_thing                  1
# ghk.jpg                        1
# xyz.jpg                        1
# something_else                 1
# def.jpg                        1

You could of course still generate a new hashtable and simply output the non-*.png keys as-is to retain the additional keys, but if you must mutate the existing one the above will work.

Note - if you're using an OrderedDictionary ($wImages = [ordered] @{ ... }) instead of a Hashtable then the order of items will change using this approach - "renamed" keys will be placed at the end of the dictionary.
